fpdf outputs wrong pdf
we have an report which is created with fpdf and output is done with
$pdf->output('I', $file);

Sometimes it occurs that User A get's output from an completely other User B (other place, other PC).
$file is always created new with a unique random filename.
The only way idea I can think of how User A gets report of User B, that there's a kind of server side caching, and server sends the wrong file from cache.
Any ideas on that? How could it happen and how to avoid it?
Thanks
Florian

How are the filenames generated? How do you guarantee their uniqueness?

it's a random string with 16 characters filled by letters and numbers. First srand((double) microtime() * 1000000), and afterwards randomly decide if letter or number and then randomly which from 0-9 or A-Z. A testing function never gave back the same value within hours. For me that's quite unique, as files are deleted after a max. of 30 minutes

"Sometimes it occurs that User A get's output from an completely other User B (other place, other PC)." - How often does this happen? Once in an hour? Once a day? How many users do you have (total, and simultaneous)?

@FiddingAway: max. I was told was 5 on one day with about 300 users (50 simultaneous)

@K J: we now decided not to use the 'D' option in output, put to first create the pdf as file, and then send to browser in a second step
